# Error de logica en JS

Tags: javascript

Tengo un error y por mas simple que parece no le puedo encontrar la lógica. Es un simple comparador de números a través de un input. el cual te informa si el valor 1 es mayor, menor o igual. Lo que sucede es que JavaScript me toma solo el primer digito que escribo, y sucede que si por ejemplo escribo en el input el numero 24 y el 4 me informa " el numero mayor es 4" y así con diferentes combinaciones pero no logro entender el error.

````
```let texto=document.getElementsByClassName('txt')
 
 
function comparar(){
    let valor1=document.getElementById('entrada1').value;
    let valor2=document.getElementById('entrada2').value;
 
    if(valor2 > valor1){
     console.log(`El número mayor es ${valor2}`)
    }
 
    else if(valor1 > valor2){
        console.log(`El número mayor es ${valor1}`)
    }
 
    else{console.log(`Los números ${valor1} y ${valor2} son iguales`)
}
}```
````

Realice lo que me comentaron Samuel y Mauricio y ahora funciona a la perfeccion. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

````
```let texto=document.getElementsByClassName('txt')


function comparar(num){
    let entrada1= document.getElementById('entrada1').value;
    let entrada2= document.getElementById('entrada2').value;
    valor1= Number.parseInt(entrada1)
    valor2= Number.parseInt(entrada2)

    if(valor1 > valor2){
     console.log(`El número mayor es ${valor1} y el número menor es ${valor2}`)
    }

    else if(valor1 < valor2){
        console.log(`El número mayor es ${valor2} y eeel número menor es ${valor1}`)
    }

    else{console.log(`Los números ${valor1} y ${valor2} son iguales`)
}
}```
````

Comment: Creo que tienes que convertir de un `String` a `Number` tus variables, puedes hacerlo de esta manera `Number(valor1)`, tiene que funcionar!

Comment: Los valores de los elementos de tipo `input` son valores de cadena, es decir, no son numéricos. La comparación que estás realizando se hace sobre cadenas, y el orden se establece lexicograficamente. Es por ello que te dice que 4 es mayor que 24, porque se toma en cuenta el orden lexicografico, donde 4 es superior a 2, y no se toma en cuenta el valor numérico de la cadena. Una opción es que conviertas el valor de tus `input` en números, usando `parseInt` por ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: @SamuelSobalvarro Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda Samuel!

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda Mauricio, se entendio a la perfeccion y junto a las dos respuestas pude solucionar este error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, tu error era:

-Como te dice en los comentarios te faltaba pasar a INT o FLOAT los Inputs

Te dejo un ejemplo con tu código funcional:

```js
function comparar(){
    let valor1=parseFloat(document.getElementById('entrada1').value);
    let valor2=parseFloat(document.getElementById('entrada2').value);
 
    if(valor2 > valor1){
     console.log(`El número mayor es ${valor2}`);
    }
 
    else if(valor1 > valor2){
        console.log(`El número mayor es ${valor1}`);
    }
 
    else{
    console.log(`Los números ${valor1} y ${valor2} son iguales`);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="entrada1">
<input type="text" id="entrada2">
<button onclick="comparar()">Comparar</button>
```